# Get value of GridView cell using jQuery without postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page which has a gridview like such :

```
<div id="output_container" class="container-fluid">
    <asp:GridView ID="EmployeeGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_ID" HeaderText="Employee ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IsManager" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png" CssClass="img-thumbnail" runat="server" Height="20" Width="20" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

This GridView is being populated by a list of objects in the code-behind which are assigning the values to the respective columns.

Now i need to write some jquery code that will detect the click event of **btnDelete** and retrieve the **isManager** value of that row, which is a boolean datatype in the backend and is hidden from the user in the view. if isManager value is true, it will pop up a confirm dialog.

Can someone help me with the code for the same? I need to detect the row in which the btnDelete is clicked and get the value of isManager of that row and display confirmation using that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a jQuery click to the ImageButton and get the value from the row by searching for the correct class in that row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= EmployeeGridView.ClientID %> .img-thumbnail").click(function () {
        var IsManager = $(this).closest('tr').find('.hidden').html();
        alert(IsManager);
    });
</script>
```

However since it is a button a PostBack will be performed. So if you want to prevent that add `OnClientClick="return false"` to the button.

Comment: Thank you so much! OnClientClick="return false" is what I needed here. However, i cut out most of the code, there is another button which has the same class as the delete button called edit button. Can i hopefully select this element using the ID and not the class name? I tried #btndelete instead of .img-thumbnail but that didn't work.

Comment: That is because there are more than one button. Give the buttons a dummy class name.